# elasticsearch couchbase transport plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I'm not sure who can help me with this so I've raised it as an issue on the github page and I'll ask here as well:

I have installed the plugin with elasticsearch version 0.19.12. Looking in elasticsearch.log the plugin seems to load successfully:

[2012-12-08 00:27:28,553][INFO ][plugins ] [Taylor, General Orell] loaded [], sites [transport-couchbase, head]
However it seems port 9091 is not being used:

david@ubuntu:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib$ nmap -p 9091 localhost

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-12-08 01:11 GMT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000089s latency).
PORT STATE SERVICE
9091/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds

I have tried specifying a port in elasticsearch.yml but that doesn't seem to make any difference. If there is somewhere more suitable I can post this then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested on my computer(s) OSX and CentOS, without any issue.

So I am inviting you to do the following, just to provide us more information to help us solving this:

- Test with the version that is documented/tested the 0.19.9 ( https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase )
- You can configure the Couchbase Transport logging by editing the ./config/logging.yml file, and add the following lines into the logger section:

  transport.couchbase: TRACE
  com.couchbase: TRACE

With this change could you please let me know if this is working, and if not if you have more informations in the logs

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied but I'm out of action until 11th Jan, I'll try it out then and get back to you.  This is something I really need to get working, perhaps it might get me into helping with elastic search as well :)

Comment: I got a reply on github:https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase/issues/2 which suggests that it's just not going to work on 0.19.12.  I actually got it working on XUbuntu with 0.20.1 so that's fair enough.  I'll mark this as answered as anyone having the same problem should first try the latest version of elasticsearch.